# React Router V4 - Initial State on Route Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Learning about React Router I noticed that a component will go back to its initial state when switching from route **a to b**.

Why the same doesn't happen when clicking over again on the same route i.e **a to a**?

How could I implement a way where clicking on the same route `<NavLink/>` the component reverts to its original state - Should/Could that be done on the `onChange` hook of React Router?

If this is an anti-pattern please enlighten me on how else I could accomplish the following: I need my component to revert to its original state not only when switching routes but also in the case that a **user chooses** to click on the same route again.

Below, an abstraction of the issue:

Clicking on the Cat `<p/>` tag should change its color to `green`, clicking on the same route `<NavLink to="/cat-view">cat</NavLink>` should revert the cat color state back to its initial state. i.e `color: false`

Just like it does when switching from route **a to b** (in my case cat to dog)

```js
// Cat Component
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Cat = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

  function ChangeColor() {
    setColor(true);
  }

  console.log(color)

  return (
    <p onClick={ChangeColor}>
      Click on this <span className={color ? "green" : " "}>Cat</span>
    </p>
  );
};
```

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Switch,
  withRouter,
  browserHistory
} from "react-router-dom";

// Main Component
class PetShop extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <NavLink to="/">home</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to="/cat-view">cat</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to="/dog-view">dog</NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/cat-view"
              render={() => <Cat/>}
              onChange={console.log("cat route changed")}
            />
            <Route
              path="/dog-view"
              render={() => <Dog/>}
              onChange={console.log("dog route changed")}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(PetShop);
```

here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wn2kp3qw9l)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using the react-router `Switch` component which only renders the first match, when you switch from Route **a** to **b**, **a** is being unmounted; this tosses out all of its state so if you switch back to **a** you have a brand new component that gets the initial value you have specified for its state (e.g. `false` for `Cat` `color`). Clicking on a `NavLink` that doesn't change the rendered `Route` leaves the same element in place and has no effect on its state.

If you want to change the state when you click on its `NavLink`, then you need to explicitly do that.
There are two main ways you could do this:

- lift the state up to the parent and explicitly change it on click of the link
- change the key of the element to force a remounting
- provide a mechanism for the parent to reach into the child and tell it to reset its state

Here's a modified version of your sandbox that demonstrates all of these:

[image: Edit react-remount-route]

`Cat` demonstrates the first approach.

I've moved the state from `Cat` up to `PetShop` (Cat now just uses props). I also added an `onClick` to the `NavLink` for cat that sets the state back to `false`.

`Dog` demonstrates the second approach.

This approach would work better in a more complicated scenario where the component has lots of its own state and you want it all to reset if you click on the link again.

`Bunny` demonstrates the third approach.

This is similar to the key property for the Dog example, but doesn't cause a remount. `Bunny` just uses the `resetIndex` in an effect to cause `Bunny` to reset itself. There are probably several technical approaches for this. You just want a way to signal the child to reset itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ryan! To your knowledge is what I'm asking for an antipattern to React's "holy grail", also would the `key` implementation as you described on the `Dog` component degrade React's performance and optimization?

Comment: @Jonca33 It largely depends on what your real scenario is. If what you want is a full reset of your component, then a remount may be appropriate, but that **will** actually remove the element (and its descendants) from the DOM and add a new element in its place. There would be some scenarios where this is fine and far easier than the alternatives, and other cases where it would not be appropriate.

Comment: @Jonca33 You also need to be careful with this approach to avoid accidentally causing it to render twice each time you click the link -- once with the old key and once with the new key.

Comment: That makes sense. My real pain (which I chose not to show here because it would be too much code verbose), is a `child` component that receives several UI changes based on user interactions. Based on your explanation am I correct to assume that would be better to do what you did to `dog` and lift the state up to remedy the situtation?

Comment: @Jonca33 I've added a third approach (Bunny) that avoids remounting, but allows the child to still control the reset (rather than needing to lift all the state up into the parent).

Comment: `props.resetRef.current`... you learn something new every day! Where can I read more about such approach? Thank you!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Comment: @Jonca33 I've added an alternative approach for the `Bunny` example

Comment: @RyanCogswell, thank you I've been looking for such a solution as well. peace!

Comment: @RyanCogswell I've been following the thread here... FYI `Bunny` stopped working when you replaced `resetRef` to  `useEffect`

Comment: @NullisTrue Thanks -- I had a syntax issue on my `useEffect` call. I wasn't enclosing `props.resetIndex` in an array.

Comment: @Jonca33 I think the ref approach is problematic so I've removed it. It had the potential to cause state updates on an unmounted component in certain scenarios.